# html page can't read from model spring boot thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have the following controller

```
package com.website.school;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "users";
    }
}
```

and a users.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Manager Site</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h1>ljkñafsñjafnjdfbhjñsdbfjñsdfvhjsdf</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="user : ${listUsers}">
                    <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${user.password}"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But whenever I run my application and navigate to /users I get the following error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/users.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/users.html]")
```

If I comment out the tbody the page loads as expected
I also know that I have a connection with my database because I made a test class that is a RestController and it returns the json I expected

#### My service class

```
package com.website.school;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

#### My Model class

```
package com.website.school;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "isAdmin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

#### My repository

```
package com.website.school;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong spelling of of the entity field `userName`.

```
<td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
```

Should be:

```
<td th:text="${user.userName}"></td>
```